# PHP to Show By Default (Call or array?)

Tags: php, wordpress, default, show, breadcrumbs

This is more of a PHP question than a WordPress question, but I am using it in a WP theme.

In my options I am allowing users to show/hide breadcrumbs.  However, when there are no preferences yet selected and saved (for example, if somebody were to install the theme) the breadcrumbs aren't displayed by default... and I would like them to be.

Below is my code.  I'm confident I'm just missing a very small piece of code here...

Here is the array I am using:

```
array( "name" => "Display breadcrumbs on post pages?",
    "desc" => "Choose whether or not to display breadcrumbs, that is, the post trail.",
    "id" => $shortname."_breadcrumbs",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => array("Yes", "No"),
    "std" => "Yes"),
```

Here is how I am calling  the breadcrumbs in my posts:

```
<?php
if ( get_option('to_breadcrumbs') == 'Yes' ) {
     if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs();
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably work

```
if ( get_option('to_breadcrumbs') != 'No' ) {
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  :-(  When the user selects no the breadcrumbs are still shown now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [default](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) value:

```
if ( get_option('to_breadcrumbs','Yes') == 'Yes' ) {
```

If that doesn't work, try putting this in and see what it prints:

```
echo get_option('to_breadcrumbs','Yes');
```