# Is there anything wrong with these if statements?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if ( get_option('to_breadcrumbs') == 'Yes' );
if ( get_option('to_breadcrumbs') != 'No' ) {
     if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs();
} ?>
```

I'm pretty new to php.  Is there anything about the code above that should be fixed?

Comment: Yes, line 2 does not make any sense. What do you want to do with that?

Comment: What does that first if do?  Doesn't look useful.

Comment: What's the link to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691953/php-to-show-by-default-call-or-array If that answer didn't solve your problem, don't mark it as accepted. Wait for another one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is syntactically correct.

```
if ( get_option('to_breadcrumbs') == 'Yes' );
```

That is not needed. There is no code being ran from outside of it.

```
if ( get_option('to_breadcrumbs') != 'No' ) {
    if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs();
}
```

This will run and do something. You can shorten it to a simple statement.

```
if (get_option('to_breadcrumbs') != 'No' and function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs'))
    dimox_breadcrumbs();
```

It is your choice to code it however you wish but the line above is preferred by most PHP programmers.

Comment: `get_option('to_breadcrumbs')` will trigger option filters in wordpress and actually execute code, but the compare is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax is correct, but the logic is not right. `get_option('to_breadcrumbs') != 'No'` means the same as `get_option('to_breadcrumbs') == 'Yes'`, assuming the value can be either yes or no.

Comment: They are two different statements though.

Answer (score 1):

The second line

```
if ( get_option('to_breadcrumbs') == 'Yes' );
```

doesn't make sense, it doesn't do anything except call `get_option()` - but the condition isn't acted upon.

The rest seems sane (not knowing what the functions actually *do* of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I would have written it like this:

```
<?ph   
//I'm assuming here that only you only want to run it if the to_breadcrumbs option is equal to yes.
if(get_option('to_breadcrumbs') == 'Yes' AND function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')){
    dimox_breadcrumbs();
}
?>
```